# Sort integer property of a list<Object>

Tags: c#

I have the following list:

```
propDataAA 4 propDataAB propDataAC
propDataBA 3 propDataBB propDataBC
propDataCA 2 propDataCB propDataCC
propDataDA 1 propDataDB propDataDC
```

I want to change the list to this:

```
propDataAA 1 propDataAB propDataAC
propDataBA 2 propDataBB propDataBC
propDataCA 3 propDataCB propDataCC
propDataDA 4 propDataDB propDataDC
```

I only want to reverse the integer property, while all other data is staying. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is your data structure? ie what are your objects? Also will the source list always have consecutive numbers 1 to n or might they just have 3, 7 and 11 or something else like that? Just wondering if you can just loop through the list setting each item or if you need to actually read out the values first...

Comment: A more meaningful example would have been helpful. Here it seems that the position of the object in the list is the new int value.

Comment: If it is truly a list<Object> you would either need to know what to cast it to, you could use linq to do the cast, or you would need to use reflection to get the property.  I think some of the answers below are ignoring that.

Comment: But you also should supply more information, and probably shouldn't use a list of object, but rather a List<AwesomePropDataObject> :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest would be to extract that property in a separate collection, order that collection and then iterate the main list updating the property with the new collection like:

```
var propertyList = yourMainList.Select(r=> r.YourProperty)
                                .OrderBy(r=> r)
                                .ToList();

//here both lists count should be same

for(int i = 0; i < yourMainList.Count; i++)
{
     yourMainList[i].YourProperty = propertyList[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.ForEach(a => a.property = list.IndexOf(a) + 1);
```

[**DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0Im8C)

Comment: The OP doesn't want to order the items but *update* the property's value

Comment: this updates the property's value by changing it to it's order in the list.  not clear though if that's the OP's intention or if he wants to reverse the numbers even if they're not in descending order